# VBA Subscript out of range - error 9

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody help me with this code, I am getting a *subscript out of range* error:

[image]

The line after the 'creating the sheets is highlighted in yellow in debugger

```
'Validation of year
 If TextBox_Year.Value = Format(TextBox_Year.Value, "0000") Then

 'Creating Process
'Creation of new sheet
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
    "" & Workbooks("Temperature Charts Sheet Creator").Sheets("MENU").Cells(4, 12).Value & "Data Sheet - " & ComboBox_Month.Value & " " & TextBox_Year.Value & ".xls", FileFormat _
    :=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:= _
    False, CreateBackup:=False

'Creating of the sheets
Windows("Data Sheet - " & ComboBox_Month.Value & " " & TextBox_Year.Value & ".xls").Activate

    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "31 " & ComboBox_Month.Value
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "30 " & ComboBox_Month.Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "29 " & ComboBox_Month.Value

For i = 28 To 1 Step -1

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = i & " " & ComboBox_Month.Value

Next
```

Answer (score 15):

Suggest the following simplification: capture return value from `Workbooks.Add` instead of subscripting `Windows()` afterward, as follows:

```
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
wkb.SaveAs ...

wkb.Activate ' instead of Windows(expression).Activate
```

*General Philosophy Advice:*

Avoid use Excel's built-ins: ActiveWorkbook, ActiveSheet, and Selection: capture return values, and, favor qualified expressions instead.

Use the built-ins only once and only in outermost macros(subs) and capture at macro start, e.g.

```
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wks = ActiveSheet
Set sel = Selection
```

During and within macros do not rely on these built-in names, instead capture return values, e.g.

```
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add 'instead of Workbooks.Add without return value capture
wkb.Activate 'instead of Activeworkbook.Activate
```

Also, try to use qualified expressions, e.g.

```
wkb.Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "foo" ' instead of Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "foo"
```

or

```
Set newWks = wkb.Sheets.Add
newWks.Name = "bar" 'instead of ActiveSheet.Name = "bar"
```

Use qualified expressions, e.g.

```
newWks.Name = "bar" 'instead of `xyz.Select` followed by Selection.Name = "bar"
```

These methods will work better in general, give less confusing results, will be more robust when refactoring (e.g. moving lines of code around within and between methods) and, will work better across versions of Excel.  Selection, for example, changes differently during macro execution from one version of Excel to another.

**Also please note that you'll likely find that you don't need to `.Activate` nearly as much when using more qualified expressions.  (This can mean the for the user the screen will flicker less.)  Thus the whole line `Windows(expression).Activate` could simply be eliminated instead of even being replaced by `wkb.Activate`.**

(Also note: I think the .Select statements you show are not contributing and can be omitted.)

(I think that Excel's macro recorder is responsible for promoting this more fragile style of programming using ActiveSheet, ActiveWorkbook, Selection, and Select so much; this style leaves a lot of room for improvement.)

Answer (score 3):

Subscript out of Range error occurs when you try to reference an Index for a collection that is invalid.

Most likely, the index in Windows does not actually include .xls. The index for the window should be the same as the name of the workbook displayed in the title bar of Excel.

As a guess, I would try using this:

```
Windows("Data Sheet - " & ComboBox_Month.Value & " " & TextBox_Year.Value).Activate
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim mode As String
Dim RecordId As Integer
Dim Resultid As Integer
Dim sourcewb As Workbook
Dim targetwb As Workbook
Dim SourceRowCount As Long
Dim TargetRowCount As Long
Dim SrceFile As String
Dim TrgtFile As String
Dim TitleId As Integer
Dim TestPassCount As Integer
Dim TestFailCount As Integer
Dim myWorkbook1 As Workbook
Dim myWorkbook2 As Workbook


TitleId = 4
Resultid = 0

Dim FileName1, FileName2 As String
Dim Difference As Long



'TestPassCount = 0
'TestFailCount = 0

'Retrieve number of records in the TestData SpreadSheet
Dim TestDataRowCount As Integer
TestDataRowCount = Worksheets("TestData").UsedRange.Rows.Count

If (TestDataRowCount <= 2) Then
  MsgBox "No records to validate.Please provide test data in Test Data SpreadSheet"
Else
  For RecordId = 3 To TestDataRowCount
    RefreshResultSheet

    'Source File row count
    SrceFile = Worksheets("TestData").Range("D" & RecordId).Value
    Set sourcewb = Workbooks.Open(SrceFile)
    With sourcewb.Worksheets(1)
      SourceRowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
      sourcewb.Close
    End With

    'Target File row count
    TrgtFile = Worksheets("TestData").Range("E" & RecordId).Value
    Set targetwb = Workbooks.Open(TrgtFile)
    With targetwb.Worksheets(1)
      TargetRowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
      targetwb.Close
    End With

    ' Set Row Count Result Test data value
    TitleId = TitleId + 3
    Worksheets("Result").Range("A" & TitleId).Value = Worksheets("TestData").Range("A" & RecordId).Value

    'Compare Source and Target Row count
    Resultid = TitleId + 1
    Worksheets("Result").Range("A" & Resultid).Value = "Source and Target record Count"
    If (SourceRowCount = TargetRowCount) Then
       Worksheets("Result").Range("B" & Resultid).Value = "Passed"
       Worksheets("Result").Range("C" & Resultid).Value = "Source Row Count: " & SourceRowCount & " & " & " Target Row Count: " & TargetRowCount
       TestPassCount = TestPassCount + 1
    Else
      Worksheets("Result").Range("B" & Resultid).Value = "Failed"
      Worksheets("Result").Range("C" & Resultid).Value = "Source Row Count: " & SourceRowCount & " & " & " Target Row Count: " & TargetRowCount
      TestFailCount = TestFailCount + 1
    End If


    'For comparison of two files

    FileName1 = Worksheets("TestData").Range("D" & RecordId).Value
    FileName2 = Worksheets("TestData").Range("E" & RecordId).Value

    Set myWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open(FileName1)
    Set myWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(FileName2)

    Difference = Compare2WorkSheets(myWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1"), myWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1"))
    myWorkbook1.Close
    myWorkbook2.Close


    'MsgBox Difference

    'Set Result of data validation in result sheet
    Resultid = Resultid + 1

    Worksheets("Result").Activate
    Worksheets("Result").Range("A" & Resultid).Value = "Data validation of source and target File"

    If Difference > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Result").Range("B" & Resultid).Value = "Failed"
        Worksheets("Result").Range("C" & Resultid).Value = Difference & " cells contains different data!"
        TestFailCount = TestFailCount + 1
    Else
      Worksheets("Result").Range("B" & Resultid).Value = "Passed"
      Worksheets("Result").Range("C" & Resultid).Value = Difference & " cells contains different data!"
      TestPassCount = TestPassCount + 1
    End If


  Next RecordId
End If

UpdateTestExecData TestPassCount, TestFailCount
End Sub

Sub RefreshResultSheet()
  Worksheets("Result").Activate
  Worksheets("Result").Range("B1:B4").Select
  Selection.ClearContents
  Worksheets("Result").Range("D1:D4").Select
  Selection.ClearContents
  Worksheets("Result").Range("B1").Value = Worksheets("Instructions").Range("D3").Value
  Worksheets("Result").Range("B2").Value = Worksheets("Instructions").Range("D4").Value
  Worksheets("Result").Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("Instructions").Range("D6").Value
  Worksheets("Result").Range("B4").Value = Worksheets("Instructions").Range("D5").Value
End Sub

Sub UpdateTestExecData(TestPassCount As Integer, TestFailCount As Integer)
  Worksheets("Result").Range("D1").Value = TestPassCount + TestFailCount
  Worksheets("Result").Range("D2").Value = TestPassCount
  Worksheets("Result").Range("D3").Value = TestFailCount
  Worksheets("Result").Range("D4").Value = ((TestPassCount / (TestPassCount + TestFailCount)))
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.