# Subscript out of range (Runtime error #9)

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a function to clear the sheet:

```
Function Clear_all(str_Sheet_Name As String)

    Sheets(str_Sheet_Name).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

End Function
```

I am trying to use this code few times its giving the error subscript out of range (Runtime error 9#) but running perfectly in other files.

Comment: None of the 8 or 9 posts with the same error (in the **Related** list to the right ====>>>>>) helped figure it out at all? Especially [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12478514/62576)?

Answer (score 0):

If the function is being called from a worksheet cell, it cannot work since this type of function can only return a value to the cell in which it resides.  The function needs to be called from a **sub**.