# excel macro issue - subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

Based on the link : [VBA Subscript out of range and Error 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363362/vba-subscript-out-of-range-and-error-9)

I am trying to do a similar thing. So I tried referring to @tim-williams answer however I still get the 
Set tbl = sht.ListObjects(TableArray(x)).Range ---- Yellow Debug error.

Is there something I am missing. I have correctly named the sheets.
[image]

Comment: Is there any chance of this error because I reference Microsoft Word 15.0 Object library ?

Comment: what does arr(x) equal, does the table exist?  what type is tbl?

Comment: I am new to Macro I exactly dont know what does arr(x) mean.. Yes the tables exist

Comment: You array, TableArray, what does tablearray(x) give, a value, if so does the table of that name exist in worksheet(x)?

Comment: Hi Nathan,Uploaded a sample file here for your reference http://www.filedropper.com/book1_9

Comment: I cant access from work, check what I've told you to check, hover over TableArray(x) and see what pops up, just below the mouse, then see if that value, exists in Worksheets(x). Click View Immediate Pane and at the point of error you can enter in there ? worksheets(x).name   ? TableArray(x)

Comment: TableArra(x) = "Sheet1" .. It exist and x=1 .. I dont know what does x=1 mean

Comment: Why are you using worksheet names to index `ListObjects`?  Is there a ListObject named `Sheet1`? Is this actually Excel (as tagged) or Word? The handler `WordDocNotFound` is ambiguous, and the linked question is for Word VBA.

Comment: I am totally new to this.. I am jus trying to get the tables exported to word.. If you could help me out I have attached a sample file here http://www.filedropper.com/book1_9

Comment: the example uses TableArray = Array("Table1", "Table2", "Table3", "Table4", "Table5")
 so it looks like it's table1 not sheet1???? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NikyRathod - since you don't even know what a lot of that code means, how can *we* really help you? Please invest some time in a good VBA tutorial. Right now, you're trying to drive a rig without knowing how to ride a bike.

Comment: @NikyRathod Please also read the [help] on asking questions. You should post the actual *code*, not a screen-shot of the code. For one thing, it's hard to read and for another, there's no way anyone can copy/paste it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Put your mouse cursor over the 'x'.  What is the value of the 'x'?  Does that table actually exist?  I'm guessing it does, but just make sure...

Can you follow this example below?

http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/10/5/multiple-tables-to-word-with-vba