# Visual Basic: Error 9

Tags: vba, subscript

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim colindexval As Double
Dim resizeval As Double
x = Sheet1.Cells(20,21).value
y = sheet1.cells(21,21).value

resizeval = Sheet1.Cells(19, 12).Value
colindexval = Sheet1.Cells(16, 12).Value
Sheet9.Range(x, y).Resize(resizeval, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B16,Sheet2!" _
& Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A12").CurrentRegion.Address & ",Sheet1!L$29,FALSE)"

End Sub
```

Running this shows:

> Error 9: subscript out of range.

I'm not familiar with this error, and am wondering if anyone can point to what I did wrong?

Comment: Variables "x" and "y" have no value

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA Subscript out of range - error 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478514/vba-subscript-out-of-range-error-9)

Comment: I set values for x and y, but still encountering this pesky error

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: It doesnt point to a line, it just gives me the error message. very weird, it doesnt even highlight anything

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't set a value for `x`, or `y`, they are defaulted to 0.

`Range(x, y)` evaluates to `Range(0, 0)` which, of course, is invalid indexing for `Range`.

That's why you get a subscript out of range error.

I think you mean to write `.Range("$A$1").Offset(x, y)` in place of `.Range(x, y)`

Comment: is any `Range(int, int)` valid?

Comment: I edited in the code and set values for x and y, but it still gives me the err9