# Excel VBA Script error Subscript out of range (Error 9)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not a specialist in VBA, but I have written a vba script for Excel, containg 12 modules with code, a lot of code. It's a very complex script but it's working fine. The problem is that it works only on my PCs. I tested it on 3 different PCs, with different Excel versions 2007, 2013 and 2016, and it works without any problem. But when I give the script to my colegues it gives errors.

Example:
This works for me:

```
Private Sub Test()

Workbooks("script").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:Z").ClearContents
......
```

It gives error Subscript out of range (Error 9) on other computers, I don't know why. If I change the code to:

```
Private Sub Test()

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:Z").ClearContents
......
```

it works on other pcs too, but if I have to change the code this way, it will take a lot of time and most importantly, I can't test it if it works after the ammendments because it works for me anyway.

I found this thread [VBA Subscript out of range - error 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478514/vba-subscript-out-of-range-error-9) but I doesn't explain why It works for me on different Excel versions and it doesn't for other people.

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745818/windows-activate-works-on-every-computer-except-one/38748754#38748754   You need to include the file extension `Workbooks("script.xlsx")` (or whatever extension it actually is)

Comment: There is also a difference between `ActiveWorkbook` (currently in focus) and `ThisWorkbook` (where the macro runs). This may cause issues if users have multiple workbooks open when running your script.

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually, the script opens 3 more files and gets/adds data from/to them. I will double check tomorrow if ActiveWorkbook is set properly, and I will add file extensions and see if it fixes the problem. I hope it does, because it will be easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that adding the file extension solves the problem as Tim suggested - 
`Workbooks("script.xlsx")`
This way it works perfetcly on all PCs. It was something very simple, but I didn't know that.

Thanks again.